# What does clicking your Mii in My Nintendo do?

Tags: my-nintendo

When you click your Mii in My Nintendo, the only thing that seems to happen is that is will jump, a orange circle will appear around him and he makes some sort of a squeeze toy sound. Is this the only thing that does happen or can I for example get coins if I click on my Mii for a specific amount of times?